# How do you become 'stylish' enough to access Luminose stores: Pokemon X and Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

So upon entering Luminose city, I immediate sought out the clothing store to look at what was offered in this city. I mean, c'mon, it's pokemon with customization? Nuts! But when I entered the store, my character was told she wasn't 'as stylish as she could be', and asked to visit other clothing stores in Luminose before returning.
Any help on how to access this particular store?

Answer (score 0):

Go into the hairdressers and cafes, (make sure you buy stuff!). Just generally interact with the buildings in Luminose City.